# Mathematica Issue

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Can someone who is familiar with mathematica tell me why my drawing wont generate?

```
plot1 = ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 0.45)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + y^2 + (z + 0.5)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.5)^2 + (z - 1.4)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 2.35)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + y^2 + (z - 3.3)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 4.25)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.5)^2 + (z - 5.2)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 6.15)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + y^2 + (z - 7.1)^2 = 0.25}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]

plot2 = ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 + (z - 0.25)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y - 0.75)^2 + (z - 1.15)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 2.05)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y - 1.25)^2 + (z - 2.95)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y - 1.5)^2 + (z - 3.85)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y - 1.75)^2 + (z - 4.75)^2 = 0.25}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
   3}, {z, -3, 3}]

plot3 = ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + (y + 0.5)^2 + z^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 1)^2 + (z - 0.75)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 1.5)^2 + (z - 1.5)^2 = 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 2.25)^2 = 0.25}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
   3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

This error comes up three time once for each plot:

```
Set::write: Tag Plus in 7.56014\[VeryThinSpace]+8.99743\[VeryThinSpace]+11.8995
 is Protected. >>

Set::write: Tag Plus in 6.24786\[VeryThinSpace]+8.99743\[VeryThinSpace]+8.99743
 is Protected. >>

Set::write: Tag Plus in 6.24786\[VeryThinSpace]+8.99743\[VeryThinSpace]+19.3562
 is Protected. >>

General::stop: Further output of Set::write will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

Comment: the "/verythinspace" is actually a thin space not part of the code.

Comment: Use == not =. You are assigning 0.25 to your equations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small syntax error
The  = symbol is used for Set (assignments and definitions)
The `==` symbol is used for Equal (equality checking)
so, in the body of each ContourPlot replace = with == and you are done

your code should be

```
plot1 = ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 0.45)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + y^2 + (z + 0.5)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.5)^2 + (z - 1.4)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 2.35)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + y^2 + (z - 3.3)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 4.25)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.5)^2 + (z - 5.2)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + (y + 0.25)^2 + (z - 6.15)^2 == 0.25, 
   x^2 + y^2 + (z - 7.1)^2 == 0.25}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 
   3}]
```

etc.

yehuda